# how to allow apostrophes in virtuemart2 product search?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have used virtuemart 2.6.6 in joomla 2.5.22

virtuemart product search works good except the search keyword having single quotes.
When i search for a keyword with single quotes it displays no results.

eg. Daniel's product

i have tried using

```
return mb_ereg_replace('-/[^\w'.preg_quote($custom).']/-', $replace, $source);
```

in config.php of virtuemart.

but still the problem occurs.

how to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at joomla.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging the search by printing the sql-code generated in the virtuemart search plugin, located in plugins/search/virtuemart/virtuemart.php. This should provide you with clues as to why the search is not working when there is an apostrophe in the search query.